# how to set first column to index using iloc[:,0]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe,and want to set first column to index using iloc[:,0],but something's wrong.

I apply iloc[:,0] to set first column to index.

```
data12 = pd.DataFrame({"b":["a","h","r","e","a"],
                       "a":range(5)})
data2 = data12.set_index(data12.iloc[:,0])
data2

    b   a
b       
a   a   0
h   h   1
r   r   2
e   e   3
a   a   4
```

I want to get the follwing result.

```
    a
b   
a   0
h   1
r   2
e   3
a   4
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the name of the Series, not the Series itself.

```
data12.set_index(data12.iloc[:, 0].name) # or data12.columns[0]
```

```
   a  
b     
a  0  
h  1  
r  2  
e  3  
a  4
```

---

From the documentation for [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

> **`keys`** This parameter can be either a single column key, a single array of the same length as the calling DataFrame, or a list containing an arbitrary combination of column keys and arrays. Here, “array” encompasses Series, Index and np.ndarray.

You need to pass a `key`, not an `array` if you want to set the index and have the respective Series no longer included as a column of the DataFrame.

Comment: thank you for your help! If i want to change the name of the index on the condition that i don't know the name of the index, so i can not use dict {"b":"A"} ,thank you !